# What does the D in "D-Ore" stand for?

Tags: meaning, american-english, abbreviations

When American journalists talk about a senator, they reference them as "D-State.Abbr.", e.g.

> Sen. X, D-Ore.

Which means X is senator of Oregon (am I right?). I want to know what does the "D" stand for?

Comment: I think you mean CNN, don't you? Or newspapers? D is Democrat.

Comment: I've just seen it in the Cyberscoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D - stands for Democrat/member of the Democratic Party

R - stands for Republican/member of the Republican Party

https://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.cfm

Comment: Democrat Party does not exist.

Comment: Democrat as in representative of the Democratic Party.

Comment: No, ***member*** of the Democratic Party. Member.

Answer (score 2):

*D* designates the senator's party affiliation: he is a "Democrat", a member of the Democratic Party.

You will also see *Sen. X, **R**-State*, meaning Senator X belongs to the Republican party, and *Sen. X, **Ind**-State*, meaning Senator X is "independent"—not formally affiliated with either party.

Comment: It is Democratic Party. And its members are Democrats.

Comment: @Lambie Quite so, and I have modified my answer; but there's no strict rule constraining whether *D-Ore* is to be read as *Democrat-Oregon* or *Democratic-Oregon*.  The grapheme is not a morpheme, much less a word--it represents a sememe.

Comment: Yes, there is strict usage. R means Republican, as in a Republican senator or a Democratic senator. You wouldn't say: Democrat senator. Members of their respective parties: The Republican Party and the Democratic Party. Now, if the word party is not present, one can say; "He is a Republican." or "She is a Democrat". But not Democrat senator or Democrat congressperson.

Comment: @Lambie But the *D* in OP's example is an unconstrained emic entity; it is constrained to a specific etic entity only in the context of a specific verbal (oral or written) utterance which paraphrases the original.

Comment: I can't get anthropological here.  Never mind.

Comment: Translation: There is nothing that indicates the D must either stand for *Democratic* or *Democrat* but Lambie is right.

Answer (score 1):

D means Democrat, or a member of the Democratic Party.

R means Republican, or a member of the Republican Party.

We say Democrat members of Congress and Republican members of Congress.

If the person is a Senator, so: Senator Widen, D-Ore, means; Senator Widen, a Democrat from the state of Oregon.

Reference: just know.

But for those who need references: [Democratic Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Party_(United_States))